# How can I delete a single image from a post with multiple images in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel 7, I can upload, add and delete all images from a task (post if it were a blog) but I am unclear on how to delete a single image from a task view (single post view). I am using resource controller for tasks but I assume I will need a different function. I created one in the same TasksController and about the resource controller, I created a delete route for it. My application complains that I am trying to get a property 'task_name' of non object when I click the single image delete button. I am not sure how to go about this or if I need to create an Image Controller (of which I am not using at the moment). I will show what I am attempting and maybe, you can tell me if I am off base or share some recommendations.  So, to start off with, here is my web.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/users', 'UsersController@index');
Route::delete('delete-image', 'TasksController@delete')->name('delete-image');

Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

My TasksController showing both my destroy method as well as my newly created delete method:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $task = Task::with('images')->findOrFail($id);

        foreach ($task->images as $image) {
            Storage::disk('public')->delete('upload/' . $image->name);
        }

        $task->images()->delete();
        $task->delete();
        return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Task Deleted');
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        //
        $task = Task::with('images')->findOrFail($id);
        $task->images()->delete();

        $images = Image::find($id);
        Storage::disk('public')->delete('upload/' . $images->name);
        $images->name()->delete();
        return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Task Deleted');
    }
```

In my show.blade.php which would act as a single post view:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                <h5>Images</h5>
                <hr />
                  <div class="row">
                      @if($task->images->count()>0)

                          @for($i=0; $i < count($images = $task->images()->get()); $i++)
                          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                            <a href="delete-image" class="badge badge-danger p-2 mb-3">Delete</a><br>
                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"><img class="w-50 mb-2" src="/storage/upload/{{ $images[$i]['name'] }}" alt=""></a>

                        </div>

                          @endfor
                          @else
                              <p>No images found</p>
                      @endif
                  </div>
                <br />
              </div>
```

In my Image.php Model my relationships are as follows:

```
public function task()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Task', 'task_id');
        // return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
    }

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::deleting(function ($images) {

            // File::delete(Storage::path($images['name']));
            File::delete(str_replace('\\', '/', storage_path('app/public/upload/' . $images->name)));
        });
    }
```

and in my Task.php Model:

```
public function images()
    {
        // return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
    }

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::deleting(function ($task) {
            foreach ($task->image ?: [] as $image) {
                $image->delete();
            }
        });
    }
```

If I missed anything, please let me know so I can modify my question. I really appreciate the help on this as I am a week behind. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the particular image_id to delete it. I have also made some changes for cleaner code:

```
<div class="row">
        @forelse($task->images as $image)
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <a href="delete-image/{{$image->id}}" class="badge badge-danger p-2 mb-3">Delete</a><br>
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox">
                <img class="w-50 mb-2" src="/storage/upload/{{ $image->name }}" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        @empty
            <p>No images found</p>
        @endforelse
</div>
```

Note that delete button now takes you to .../delete-image/{image_id}

then on controller find the id and delete it.

Update your route file to accept id as Variable

```
Route::delete('delete-image/{image_id}', 'TasksController@delete')->name('delete-image');
```

then on controller variable can be accessed as

```
public function delete($image_id, Request $request)
{
    # code...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hásil. I am closer. I am having trouble finding the id in my controller. Any advice? The route keeps taking me to a 404. I can see the url with the id of the image. :
`public function delete(Image $image)
    {
        //
        // $task = Task::with('images')->findOrFail($id);
        $images = Image::find();
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            dd($image->id);
            Storage::disk('public')->delete('upload/' . $image->name);
        }
        $images->delete();
        return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Image Deleted');
    }`

Comment: Thank you @Hásil. I changed the code as per your suggestion but I am still getting a 404 page as if it is not finding the controller. 2 things, I wonder if , one, that fact that the image has a relationship with its task and that is why or if I have not image_id in my images table. I am at a loss. Sorry to be a pest.

Comment: Thank you @Hásil. I got the image to delete from my disk as well as from my db. The only thing left is that after implementing the code you suggested, I cannot see my images. If I use `<img src="/storage/upload/{{$image->name}}">` I get the error ` Property [name] does not exist on this collection` . Any clues? Thanks again

Comment: Either $image object does not contain name key, or $image is an array. Firstly, dd($image) and check if name exists, and try $image['name'].

also i suggest using asset() function available on laravel for getting exact url.
<img src="{{ asset($image->name) }}" >

Comment: Thanks @Hásil. Here was the problem. I changed the image tag to: `<img src="/storage/upload/{{ $images[$i]['name'] }}"  class="w-50 mb-2" alt="">` Fixed now. Thank you.